# Container don't wanna blur with js function

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, blur

I'm setting up a website, and I want to blur a container when I click on a button.

I've tried to add a "blur" class on my container with a js function

```js
var vid = document.getElementById("bgvid");
vid.volume = 0.01;
var x = document.getElementById("formregister");
var container = document.getElementById('container');

function hideShow() {
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    container.setAttribute('class', 'blur');
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
    container.setAttribute('class', null);
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.bg,
.bg-filter {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  z-index: -100;
}

.bg-filter {
  z-index: -99;
  opacity: 0.2;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(49, 224, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 77, 184, 1) 100%);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(49, 224, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 77, 184, 1) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(49, 224, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 77, 184, 1) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(49, 224, 247, 1) 0%, rgba(90, 77, 184, 1) 100%);
}

.top_vid {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.top_vid .title {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  margin-left: 3%;
  font-size: 3.2em;
  color: #fff;
}

.start {
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  border-radius: 4px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 28px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 3%;
}

.start span {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.start span:after {
  color: #31E0F7;
  content: '\00bb';
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: -20px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.start:hover span {
  padding-right: 25px;
}

.start:hover span:after {
  opacity: 1;
  right: 0;
}

.registerform {
  align-items: center;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <video autoplay loop poster muted class="bg" id="bgvid">
    <source src="http://cdn-b-east.streamable.com/video/mp4/xoecp.mp4?token=TvBJWgOGquHb07Q5IlkCZA&expires=1558304940" type="video/mp4"></source>
  </video>

  <div class="bg-filter" id="bg-filter"></div>

  <div class="top_vid">
    <h1 class="title">Moodyness</h1>
    <button class="start" onclick="hideShow()"><span>Let's move !</span></button>
  </div>

</div>

<div class="registerform" id="formregister" style="display: none;">

  <form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="email" placeholder="EMAIL" required></input>
    <input type="password" placeholder="PASSWORD" required></input>
    <input type="password" placeholder="REPEAT PASSWORD" required></input>

    <div class="check">
      <label for="checkbox">Acceptez vous les conditions d'utilisation ?</label>
      <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" required></input>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Okay !"></input>
  </form>

</div>
```

I want everything except the new form to be blured and the form to be shown but it doesn't seems to work, in the codepen it doesn't blur, and in my pc it make the whole body move to the top of the page.

Thanks you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? 
https://jsfiddle.net/Lrfyowc3/

I first added a period before "blur" in the css. Secondly I added id="top_vid" to the html for the text at the top. Thirdly, I added a variable for "top_vid" and added the following to the javascript:

```
      vid.className += " blur";
   top_vid.className += " blur";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add or remove a class using the classList.add() and classList.remove() methods.

[classList Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

And another detail, in your css you forgot to add a "." before the blur, so you selector is for a tag blur not a class blur, so you should change to the following:

```
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(10px); 
}
```

To add the blur class

```
vid.classList.add('blur');
```

To remove the blur class

```
vid.classList.remove('blur');
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, it almost work, but the video in background still does move, like a margin ? Have you an idea ?

Comment: I'll take look, but it shouldn't add a margin

Comment: Seems like if you change the blur from the container to the video element it works, i'll edit my awnser

Answer (score 0):

ok , i found it in CSS Change blur to .blur and write z-index
:-100 and run

```css
.blur {
  -webkit-filter: blur(2px);
  -moz-filter: blur(2px);
  -ms-filter: blur(2px);
  -o-filter: blur(2px);
  filter: blur(2px); 
  z-index:-100
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, same as the other comment, my video still move when I do this, I can't find out why